# How to add file in My Documents folder like Whatsapp?

Tags: android, cordova

I want to create a directory in android like whatsapp to store some files. But I cannot create a file in android. I only can create files /directories in my package (for example com.exampleapp.org)...

My goal is to add a new file in "my documents" directory of android 4.3...

In my AndroidManifest.xml I have set following permissions: `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Has anyone an idea? Is this possible with "only" phonegap or do I need a new plugin?

I am using cordova 3.4.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get Documents directory you should use [`Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).

To access it:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)
```

---

> Standard directory in which to place documents that have been created
> by the user.

Other directory:

> public static String  **DIRECTORY_ALARMS**    Standard directory in which to
> place any audio files that should be in the list of alarms that the
> user can select (not as regular music).
>
> public static
> String    **DIRECTORY_DCIM**  The traditional location for pictures and videos
> when mounting the device as a camera.
>
> public static
> String    **DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS** Standard directory in which to place
> documents that have been created by the user.
>
> public static
> String    **DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS** Standard directory in which to place files
> that have been downloaded by the user.
>
> public static
> String    **DIRECTORY_MOVIES**    Standard directory in which to place movies
> that are available to the user.
>
> public static
> String    **DIRECTORY_MUSIC** Standard directory in which to place any audio
> files that should be in the regular list of music for the user. public
> static String DIRECTORY_NOTIFICATIONS Standard directory in which to
> place any audio files that should be in the list of notifications that
> the user can select (not as regular music).
>
> public static
> String    **DIRECTORY_PICTURES**  Standard directory in which to place
> pictures that are available to the user.
>
> public static
> String    **DIRECTORY_PODCASTS**  Standard directory in which to place any
> audio files that should be in the list of podcasts that the user can
> select (not as regular music).
>
> public static
> String    **DIRECTORY_RINGTONES** Standard directory in which to place any
> audio files that should be in the list of ringtones that the user can
> select (not as regular music).

Comment: I guess there is no way with the phonegap api to do this?